# How can I save state of tabs in Safari?

Tags: mac, safari

I am macOS rookie and now have difficulties with Safari, I would like to find how I can save tabs?

For example some tabs were open, than I close Safari and turn off laptop, next time when I turn on laptop and open Safari I would like my tabs restored and open again...

Comment: Please comply with the apple.stackexchange guidelines and ask one question by question. Also: macOS provides an excellent Help system which is also available in the Internet: [History](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21477?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US), [Tabs](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21444?locale=en_US)

Comment: Related question on SU with a possible alternative working answer: https://superuser.com/questions/938409/safari-save-window-session-like-tabcloud-for-chrome

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To see your entire history, select **Show All History** on the History menu, or press Cmd-Y.

To restore your tabs after each restart, open Preferences from the Safari menu, go to the General tab, and select **Safari Opens With All Windows from Last Session**.

The main advantages to using Safari over Chrome are its better system integration, which you may or may not care about. Examples of this are proper use of the Notification Centre, ability to AirPlay (some) videos from your browser to other AirPlay devices, iCloud password and bookmark syncing between devices, and Handoff when you want to open a page on your Mac, and continue reading it on your iOS device (or vice versa).

Historically, Chrome has also been a bit of CPU hog compared to Safari, which ultimately impacts your battery life. I haven't checked recently whether that's still the case.

Comment: you know that I noticed, when close safari with red cross in left top corner and  then reopen it is appear with new window, but if I close safari with `cmd + q` and then reopen it open and restore all tabs... ok, but why is this difference? if I can change it? any idea

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Clicking the red cross only closes the window, it doesn't terminate the application.

Comment: @patrix ok, but in this case, if it only close the window why when I click on icon on the bottom it open new window? Or if window was closed it means that all tabs also are closed?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko If you close a window all tabs are gone (and will not be restored later on). The option to save the state *saves all open windows and tabs within these windows* when you leave/quit Safari with Cmd-Q.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko If you click on the Safari icon in the Dock ("icon on the bottom") while Safari is still running, Safari will switch to the front and automatically open a new window if there isn't one open already. It does not mean an application restart.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Also see the answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190785/safari-does-not-restore-saved-tabs-when-i-exit-via-x-icon?rq=1

Comment: 3 years later: yes, that’s still the case.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Safari extension [SessionRestore](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.sweetpproductions.sessionrestore-U928YCMMNK). It's similar to [SessionBuddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) for Chrome. It lets you save a session manually, give it a name, autosave your tabs every so many minutes, and easily restore.

[image]

What it doesn't appear to do is let you edit an already-saved session the way SessionBuddy does.

Answer (score 2):

I have develop this open source Tab Manager for Safari, and I think it's what you need.I hope you like it. All the comments are welcome.

https://github.com/morsamatias/UltraTabSaver

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> closes safari and all tabs are "remembered" so that the next time you reopen safari, those tabs will re-appear. Of course if you close tabs or close all tabs, you can always restore those tabs as described above (under the history section on the toolbar).

I've noticed that if I close safari by using the red button on the top left, when you reopen, you start of clean. So use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to close and keep your tabs for the next reopen.

> [image: []]

These settings are in System Preferences → General.

Comment: Correct. This is in fact default behaviour now for a lot of Apple software.

Comment: Mind if I include this picture in your answer? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dot5Z.png (notify me by @ankii)

Answer (score 1):

This [blog](https://heresthethingblog.com/2017/06/29/save-safari-tabs-bookmark-folder/) answers the core part of the question without requiring any extensions. It does not cover automatic opening of saved tabs but is still useful.

TL;DR

1. Access Safari menu Bookmarks > Add Bookmarks for These x Tabs...
2. Select a Bookmarks Folder and give a name to your session
3. When you want to access the session, right-click the folder and "Open in New Tabs" or "Automatically Replace Tabs"