# Browsers don't restore tabs after quitting in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, web-browser, browser-history

I'm new to Mac, so please be patient :)

I've got a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) with macOS Mojave. Some apps are pre-installed, because it's a company laptop. So, maybe something in there, but I'm not sure.

The problem is that neither Safari nor Vivaldi (I installed Vivaldi to check there) restore opened tabs. But Safari has an option "Safari opens with: All windows from last session" and Vivaldi "Startup: Last session". On my Ubuntu Desktop Vivaldi works perfectly with it.

So, what's going on here and how to fix it?

## Update due to comments:

- I'm not using Incognito, so that's not the problem
- I unchecked the *Close windows when quitting an app* option in System Preferences > General but this didn't help
- I've checked the answers at [How can I save state of tabs in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263310/how-can-i-save-state-of-tabs-in-safari) but none of the answers helped, so it seems this problem is unique to macOS Mojave (especially since Vivaldi is also affected)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you make sure you were not browsing in Incognito mode?

Comment: also ...  menu > System Prefs > General - see if 'Close windows when quitting an app' is checked. For the behaviour you want, it should not be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save state of tabs in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263310/how-can-i-save-state-of-tabs-in-safari)

Comment: When you say the duplicate question "didn't help", why didn't it help or what didn't work?  Usually, we prefer you don't create a brand-new question for a duplicate problem unless your situation is so different that the supplied answers wouldn't apply.  I'm not seeing that here.

Comment: Because it really didn't help. I went through all steps here and there. Should I attach screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have found a bug,
I can reproduce your issue on my Mac running 10.14.1

It does work after logging out (and back in) or force closing Safari,
but when I close it normally and reopen, it does not reopen my last session,
until I click reopen last closed tab, and it suddenly restores all my tabs from the last session. Bit annoying but at least a work around (Cmd + Shift + T)

I needs a bit more testing I think, but looks like this should be reported to Apple if this behaviour is indeed consistent.

Comment: The best workaround right now - don't close browser :)
Anyway, I don't power off my Mac for 2 weeks so far.

Comment: If it's a bug, it's not affecting everyone, so some other factor must be involved. Been running Mojave since the first beta [& am currently on 10.14.2 b3] & whilst I don't quit & relaunch Safari a lot I have done it many times over the past few months & have never seen this issue.